# ¿Por qué no funciona ".dispose()" en mi código? (JAVA)

Tags: java, jframe

Buenos días y saludos a todos.

Tengo un JFrame principal (main) que es un formulario de LOGIN.
En este JFrame principal (main) tengo un botón de "Crear usuario" que lleva a otro JFrame (frameNuevoUsuario).

Necesito que al hacer click en el botón "Crear usuario" se habrá el JFrame nuevo (frameNuevoUsuario) y se cierre el anterior (main).

El problema de mi código es que me abre el nuevo JFrame, pero no me cierra el anterior. No me funciona ni `.dispose()` ni `.setVisible(false)`.

En un principio he creado este método:

```
public void cerrarFrame() {
    frameNuevoUsuario nuevousuario = new frameNuevoUsuario();
    nuevousuario.setVisible(true);

    main esteFrame = new main();
    esteFrame.dispose();
```

Y lo he metido tal cual en el botón:

```
botonCrearUsuario = new JButton("Crear usuario");
botonCrearUsuario.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {     
        cerrarFrame();
```

Pero nada macho, que no me funciona. Os dejo el código acortado del JFrame porque seguro será de utilidad para ver donde estoy metiendo la pata. **Gracias de antemano**.

```
package proyectoBiblioteca;

    // "IMPORTS" QUE HE BORRADO PARA ACORTAR EL CÓDIGO

public class main extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JPasswordField passwordField;
    JButton botonCrearUsuario;
    String nombreUsuario;
    String contrasena;

    //FRAME PRINCIPAL
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    main frame = new main();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        //CREAR TABLAS EN BASE DATOS        
        try {        
            Connection miConexion = DriverManager.getConnection("JDBC:sqlite:biblioteca.db");               
            Statement miState = miConexion.createStatement();               
            String sentenciaSQL = "CREATE TABLE usuarios(usuario VARCHAR UNIQUE, password VARCHAR)";                
            miState.execute(sentenciaSQL);        
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
    }


    // FRAME
    public main() {
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("iLibrary");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 379);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        // BOTONES QUE HE BORRADO PARA ACORTAR EL CÓDIGO

        botonCrearUsuario = new JButton("Crear usuario");
        botonCrearUsuario.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                cerrarFrame();
            }
        });

        botonCrearUsuario.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        botonCrearUsuario.setBounds(96, 243, 258, 23);
        contentPane.add(botonCrearUsuario);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);    
    }

    public void cerrarFrame() {
        frameNuevoUsuario nuevousuario = new frameNuevoUsuario();
        nuevousuario.setVisible(true);

        main esteFrame = new main();
        esteFrame.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void cerrarFrame() {
    frameNuevoUsuario nuevousuario = new frameNuevoUsuario();
    nuevousuario.setVisible(true);

    main esteFrame = new main();
    esteFrame.dispose();
```

Fíjate en lo que estás haciendo. Estás creando un nuevo frame `esteFrame` e inmediatamente lo estás cerrando. Simplemente cambia el código de la funcion cerrarFrame() por el siguiente:

```
public void cerrarFrame() {

    frameNuevoUsuario nuevousuario = new frameNuevoUsuario();
    nuevousuario.setVisible(true);

    dispose();
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Pablo. Justo era lo que pasaba. Ando gateando en Java aún y pensaba que tenía que crearle el objeto al frame :)

Comment: Ánimo, poco a poco y fallando es como se aprende. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que estás intentando cerrar un frame que no es el que muestras.

Tienes:

```
public void cerrarFrame() {
    frameNuevoUsuario nuevousuario = new frameNuevoUsuario();
    nuevousuario.setVisible(true);

    main esteFrame = new main();
    esteFrame.dispose();
}
```

Prueba cambiándolo a:

```
public void cerrarFrame() {
    frameNuevoUsuario nuevousuario = new frameNuevoUsuario();
    nuevousuario.setVisible(true);

    this.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Hola. Has respondido exactamente lo mismo que le he puesto yo, pero después. Para eso está el botón de votar respuesta útil. Un saludo!

Comment: @PabloGonzález si te fijas la diferencia en los tiempos de publicación es de 1 minuto. Esto me hace pensar que quizás ambos hayan estado redactando sus respuesta casi al mismo tiempo, por lo que quiero pensar que fue solo una coincidencia. Saludos.

Comment: Es posible, no me había fijado. Saludos!!